# Spring project on microservices got confused with dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to create a test project on microservices. I took another project as a basis.
Here is the structure of the project:

```
octory
--common
--proxy-service
--content
```

At the root of the project, I created the main pom.xml

```
<groupId>ru.octory.marketplace</groupId>
<artifactId>octory</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.12</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>content</module>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>proxy-service</module>
</modules>
```

pom.xml common module

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>octory</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.octory.marketplace</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>common</name>
<description>Common MicroService</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

pom.xml proxy-service module

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>octory</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.octory.marketplace</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>proxy-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>proxy-service</name>
<description>Proxy-service MicroService</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <common.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</common.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.octory.marketplace</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>${common.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>proxy</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

The common module was assembled without errors.
But when I run mvn clean install in the proxy-service module, an error occurs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project proxy-service: Could not resolve dependencies for project ru.octory.marketplace:proxy-service:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at ru.octory.marketplace:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHO
T: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ru.octory.marketplace:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact ru.octory.marketplace:octory:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

This is the first time I'm trying to create a project on microservices and I'm completely confused about dependencies.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running `mvn clean install` in the parent folder?

Comment: Yes, the same error on the same module

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the folder with local repositories /home/<user_name>/.m2 helped Only after that the error went away.

Comment: Then it seems you had some corrupted files there.